# Wanderer warrior or warrior wanderer?

Tags: nouns

Is "wanderer warrior" a wanderer who is a warrior or a warrior who is a wanderer? Which is the "main" noun here? Or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to give a bit more explanation. Have you actually encountered this phrase? Can you give a source? Ultimately, I think it has less to do with "main noun, modifying noun" and more to do with the fact that some are more in the habit of serving as modifiers. "Warrior king" is common enough; "king warrior" [not so much](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=warrior+king%2Cking+warrior&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwarrior%20king%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cking%20warrior%3B%2Cc0). But neither of your proposed phrases seem to be common.

Comment: [Inspirassion](https://inspirassion.com/en/nn/warrior) lists 185 (perhaps including repeats) of collocations of the form [warrior][noun2] (eg warrior chief; warrior-princess; warrior ancestors) but none of the form [noun1][warrior]. That said, neither 'wanderer warrior' nor 'warrior wanderer' sounds all that natural.  // I'd say 'warrior-priest' has no clear head, though it's irreversible. But usually the head comes last in the collocation / compound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the structure of English compound nouns like this, a "wanderer warrior" is more likely to be a warrior who is a wanderer.

This type of compound can be classified as an [attributive compound](https://notendur.hi.is/%7Eantoni/docs/ingason2020attributive.pdf), where both words in the compounds are nouns and one modifies the other. As Ingason and Sigurðsson point out, "English compounds - and compounds in other Germanic languages, for that matter - are generally right-headed," meaning that the rightmost noun is the head noun and the other noun is the modifier.

In "wanderer warrior," *warrior* would be the head noun according to this tendency, so a "wanderer warrior" would be a type of warrior.